# Access OBD2 data remotely

Tags: reverse-engineering, gsm, obd-ii

I am really confused about the operation of the OBD2. I have always thought that it is read only, and I see these apps starting there car remotely using OBD dongles.
How do they get the stats remotely?
If I would to use an arduino with GSM, what procedure do I need to make it work with my phone?
The tutorials I've seen were about close range using Bluetooth.
Any tutorials about this project?

I am not asking for step by step, but a path to achieve that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The standard OBD-II commands will not allow you start a car.

However, there may be manufacturer extensions or non-standard mechanisms which do enable this - I am not aware of any manufacturer making this publicly available.

Obviously there are serious security and safety implications for this type of access, but there have been reported 'hacks' (e.g. https://www.wired.com/2015/07/hackers-remotely-kill-jeep-highway/) that do allow access, although you would expect (and hope if you are in the car) that these are rectified when reported.